# Last element is being left out

Tags: javascript

I've got this block of code which supposed to convert string into a list of elements while
filtering out spaces at the same time:

```
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  //console.log(numbers);
  let b = [];
  let to_push = '';
  for (let x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
    if (numbers[x] === ' ') {
      b.push(parseInt(to_push));
      to_push = '';
    } else {
      to_push += numbers[x];
    }
   }
  return b;
}

highAndLow('34 11 -5 9');
```

It works except from the fact that the last element from the string is being left out. The `let x = 0; x < numbers.length` should've taken care of but it didn't. Adding 1 to numbers.length didn't help. It shouldn't anyway.

Comment: `numbers.split(' ').map(it => parseInt(it.trim(), 10))` <= to get an array of numbers.

Comment: @Taplar isn't 10 the default radix for `parseInt` ?

Comment: I don't like to rely on defaults.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that I'm learning fundamentals of JavaScript from 5 years old book. Had excellent reviews.

Comment: `'34 11 -5 9'.split(' ').map(Number)`

Comment: The problem is you need to see if it is ' ' or if it is the last index

Comment: @mr_incredible JavaScript had a *major* overhaul called ES6 or ECMAScript2015 in 2015. Make sure your book at least covers this version.

Comment: @Seblor  Thanks for the heads-up. Actually I know about ES6 as I'm learning about ReactJs at the same time. The book is great at learning prehistoric JavaScript while the React course is teaching me about ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to see if you have anything after the for loop

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  //console.log(numbers);
  let b = [];
  let to_push = '';
  for (let x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
    if (numbers[x] === ' ') {
      b.push(parseInt(to_push));
      to_push = '';
    } else {
      to_push += numbers[x];
    }
   }
  if (to_push) {
    b.push(parseInt(to_push));
  }
  return b;
}

var result = highAndLow('34 11 -5 9');
console.log(result)
```

Other option is append a space to the end of the string

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  numbers = numbers + " ";
  let b = [];
  let to_push = '';
  for (let x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
    if (numbers[x] === ' ') {
      b.push(parseInt(to_push));
      to_push = '';
    } else {
      to_push += numbers[x];
    }
   }
  return b;
}

var result = highAndLow('34 11 -5 9');
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a better and simpler approach.
We also use `filter` function to remove empty strings created by the `split` function if the numbers are separated by more than one space character (Example s2).

```js
function highAndLow (string) {
  return string.split(' ').filter(s => s !== '').map(s => Number(s));
}

let s1 = '1 2 3 -4 5'
let s2 = '  2    -4   5   '

console.log(highAndLow(s1))
console.log(highAndLow(s2))
```

Comment: filter is not really needed. Simple trim and reg exp cleans it up `string.trim().split(/\s+/).map(Number)`